# На маленьких размерах nav отодвигает контент расположенный ниже его

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, bootstrap

Нужно сделать так, чтобы в bootstrap 3 nav на маленьких размерах экрана(<768px) при нажатии на кнопку выпадающего меню
[image: фотография выпадающего меню]

выпадающее меню отодвигало нижнюю часть контента, а не налезало на него, как в примере:
[image: фотография вида из браузера]
Вот код:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-defaul " role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header"> 
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse"> 
            <span class="sr-only">МЕНЮ</span> 
            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
        </button> 
    </div> 

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse"> 
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">ГЛАВНАЯ</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">КАТАЛОГ</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ДИЛЛЕРАМ</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ЗАКАЗЧИКИ</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">НОВОСТИ</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ОТЗЫВЫ</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">КОНТАКТЫ</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Вот css-код:

```
.info {
    width: 100%;
    height: 750px;
    background: url(../res/infobg.png) ;
    background-position: center;
}
.info .menu{
    height: 25px;
}
    .menu ul {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .menu ul li{
        width: 14.28571428571429%;
    }

    .menu a {
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff;
        font-family: 'Roboto', regular;
        font-size: 18px;
    }

    .menu a:hover , .menu a:focus{
        background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.1) !important;
    }

button.navbar-toggle {
    background-color: white;
}

span.icon-bar {
    background-color: #095C9F;
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {    
    .menu li {
        width: 100% !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ заключался в удаление этой строки css-кода:

```
.info .menu{
   height: 25px;
}
```